# Unable to set font family style to spark button in flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I have created a style in which i am defining a font family.When i apply this style to label it reflects the font were as there is no change when it is applied to a spark button.I Tried various way to Apply font style but it doesn't work.Other properties work fine except font family. Even i tried creating skin class and set the font family style of label in it. While previewing the skin i can see the changes but when i apply it to button, it shows the default font. Below given code is written in a View.I had followed 2 approaches but none of them work.

### **Approach 1**

```
@font-face{
src:url("HARNGTON.TTF");
fontFamily: MyF;
embed-as-cff: false;
}

<s:Button x="143" y="108" width>="471" label="Course" color="white" fontFamily="MyF"
>
```

**Approach 2**

I have created a style and i m also using skin class for button.I have not defined font family in skin class. So i hope button is not overriding the font-family from skin class i.e the default value.

```
@font-face{
src:url("HARNGTON.TTF");
fontFamily: MyF;
embed-as-cff: false;
}
.myFont
{
fontFamily: MyF;
}

<s:Button x="143" y="108" width="471" label="Course" color="white" styleName=myFont skinclass="MyButton_skin">
```

I tried using CSS file also but it is still not working.
Sample of CSS file is as follows:

/* CSS file */

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

@font-face{
    src:url("/views/abc.ttf");
    fontFamily: MyF;
    fontWeight:bold;
    embed-as-cff: false;
}

s|Button {
    fontFamily: MyF;
    color: #000000;
    fontSize: 34;
}
```

and i used it during initialization of view

```
public function init():void{
                styleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("Basic.swf",true);
            }
```

But still there is no change in the font style.

Comment: How did you create the style?  Where did you put the style?  How are you trying to set the style on the button?  I believe you can answer all three of those questions by editing your question and providing some code.  We need to know what you have done before  providing suggestions for what you may have done wrong (or right).

Comment: i have updated the question. i hope that clears the question.And i have more doubt. Are there any specific kind of fonts that can only be used with button??

Comment: You could also set the font-weight="normal" attribute of the button. But you should look to the CSS-based solution of this problem.

Comment: can you provide an sample example or any link which shows the us of CSS file to set the font style to a button. I dint find any useful examples for it

Comment: tried using CSS file but it is not working.I have added the code above

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens because you embed a font with `normal` weight. Buttons use a `bold` label. If you embed a font as normal, and use it as bold, it won't be rendered correctly.

Unless you specify that the embedded font is bold (in the font-family declaration, set the `font-weight` property to `bold`), it will not be added to the button label.

After looking at the code you posted, it's evident that the font-family declaration, does not define the weight of the embedded font, so Flex assumes it is set to `normal`. That's why you don't see the label with the embedded font.

Comment: I made the changes which you mentioned above but it is still not working                                                    @font-face
{
fontFamily:"Mybutton";
fontWeight:bold;
src: url("assets/segoesc.ttf");
embedAsCFF: false;
}
<s:Button id="b1" x="10" y="83" width="141" height="43" skinClass="Mymobileskin.MyButton" label="Customize11" color="#EA1A1A" fontFamily="Mybutton" />

Answer (score 0):

When using fonts with Spark components you should set the embedAsCFF to true not false. False is used when embedding fonts in a legacy mx component.

Answer (score 0):

pixels4nickels is right, firstly you need to set embedAsCFF : true, secondly, I do not think embed-as-cff is not the right format, should be embedAsCFF